# xCode7 StackViews inside ScrollView overlapping views

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, constraints, uistackview, xcode7.2

this is my first job with xCode and I'm migrating an Android App to IOs. I'm attempting to create a ScrollView with some items inside of its content view. Below is a print of the Storyboard tree:

[image]

When I run the app, the items below the selected StackView, including it, do not appear correcly on the simulator. They are all overlapped at the top of the screen:

[image]

I have already double checked all the constraints, along with other properties on the views but could not find the issue. Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

## =========================================

Thanks, Imran. This helped me find the issue. But I still would like to understand it. As you can see from the picture below, some of the views in my storyboard have this "wAny hR" property set. Literally all the stackviews and, the Labels and Buttons which were messy. Once I remove this property and set the "Installed" one, they showed up ok. Any thoughts on that?

[image]

Comment: Notice the blue bar at the bottom of the first screen shot. This means you have designed your interface using the Vary for Traits button, making them conditional on the current size classes. This suggests possible confusion. Did you know what you were doing or were you just thrashing around?

Comment: Also: Xcode 7? Really? When the rest of the world is using Xcode 12 or even 13? What will you do with an app created with Xcode 7? You can't submit it to the App Store. Is this just an exercise for your own computer alone?

Comment: @matt, I have a MacBook Pro Early 2011, running Yosemite (Could not clean install it with HighSierra as it would not). So, xCode 7.2 is the max I could get. 
Regarding the blue bar, I think I just trashed it as you mentioned. I'm removing all the references to it from my views.

Comment: Well what I'm saying is that trying to do any iOS development with that machine is pointless. If you have a "job" where you are actually supposed to produce a usable app, you are not doing that job. You will not be able to write an up to date app and you will not be able to submit it to the App Store, so you are just playing around privately. You must get newer hardware and newer software or you can't even get started. Moreover you will get very little useful help from us if you use an iOS / Xcode version that is so much older than all of us are using.